# How to name keys in a Localizable file strings

Tags: ios, swift, string, localizable.strings

how to set name for keys in `Localizable.strings`
I don't know that keys in Localizable.strings on what basis are they named?

for example :

I have a view that it's including title and sub title, but I'm confused for key's name in localizable file .

Comment: Have you successfully implemented MDM?

Comment: Any structure that makes the usage clear. It's like a variable name. e.g. `menu.title`, `settings.notifications.enabled` etc. Usually it's a good idea to also add comments for every text.

Comment: for example for title login button I can to set "login_button" = "Log in"; but  I in key is in different places of the app and I confused that it key is for where ? @Sulthan

Comment: If you have a key that is used in multiple spaces just give it a common prefix, e.g. `common` or a prefix depending on its usage. It's like a global variable. The key should concisely describe how the text is used. Use the comment for any other information.